# Search is not working on plugin directory

Tags: plugins, search

When i click on add new button and search new plugin in plugin directory and click on search plugin button, it shows no result. How to enable searching in plugin directory? plz help. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: May this help : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/wordpress-plugin-search-does-not-work-and-updates-are-not-shown-vps-install

Comment: Thank you! @jas. I had seen it earlier. But i dont think that it can help in my case. This problem is occur after updating wordpress to 4.6.1

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the request that WP is making to query the Plugin site is not being allowed by your installation, or your hosting place. As per the link that was given you in the comments to your question.